# Map pdf pages to certain text on pages

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

I need to open a pdf file from excel at a certain page. The problem is that actual pdf pages and sheet numbers used in excel do not match. For example page 7 in pdf is referenced as sheet 111 in excel, page 8 in pdf is referenced as sheet 121 in excel. The pdf file is an electrical drawing, that is why sheet numbers are arranged by function without any logical relation to the actual pdf page numbers.

Comment: The solution was to convert pdf with pdftotext.exe into a textfile, pull out the sheet numbers of schema and map them with pdf page numbers. Further it was straightforward to run the pdf with correct page number.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to convert pdf with pdftotext.exe into a textfile, pull out the sheet numbers of schema and map them with pdf page numbers. Further it was straightforward to run the pdf with correct page number.